# What will be the final product?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I think water will attack at double bond and epoxy but I don't know how to proceed further, how is the answer B?

Comment: Consider what the site of first protonation is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the path below fully shows what happens.
[image]